# How to get a mortgage with low income but good assets

Tags: united-states, mortgage, loans, california

I have low income about $50,000 a year since divorce.  But I am about to sell my house for $2 million, and possible gain about $1M profit.  I can put a down payment of $300,000 to down size to a house that cost about $600,000.

Is it possible for me to find a bank who can approve me for $350,000 so I can buy the house in the $600,000 range since there is nothing else below that price range in Los Angeles?

Comment: You might want to ask at the bank, but you are probably better off just paying cash for a home.

Comment: There are lenders (though probably not banks) that do this.  Search for "asset based mortgage".

Answer (score 3):

Why would you need a mortgage to buy a $600,000 house, if you have a gain of $1,000,000 from your previous house (in cash)?

But 7x your annual income is a fairly high mortgage, I guess it would be only a very few banks who would be willing to help you out with that. Remember that what is important for a bank, is your ability to service your loan - you cannot service your loan with equity stashed away in a house.

As a general rule, the amount of savings you have will not influence the amount of money you can borrow in such a situation. That being said, it is not entirely true because most banks will be willing to lend you more if you have a decent savings - but stricly speaking, theoretically, then the amount would be the same.

Comment: Income is key for loans because there's nothing stopping you from going out any buying a $500K _boat_ after closing the mortgage, then you can't afford to pay the mortgage. Lenders assume (rightfully) that there's a _reason_ you aren't putting those extra assets toward the house.

Comment: Exactly! ..and if you have the cash/money, why take out a loan rather than using the savings instead.

Comment: @ssn: Because the mortgage interest is at 3-4%, while my mutual funds have been returning 7-8%?

Comment: @jamesqf: Yes, but this is not the subject of the matter - now we are talking the possibility to obtain mortgages with debt-to-income in the level of 7x. Also risk-wise the two are vastly different: 1) is investing money you should (in theory) be able to afford losing, 2) is a real asset where you can live even in economic downturns where your mutual fund may return negative profits. Not everyone is willing to, or should, take that risk.

Comment: Yes that is my dilemma.  If I have $1M+ in cash, do I want to put most of it in a house or diversify it in other investments like stock/mutual funds?  Would love to hear all thoughts and arguments.  Learn so much on here from everyone.

Comment: @ssn: Well, you're the one that asked :-)  And as I mentioned above, there are such things as asset-based mortgages.  But if I'm understanding the OP correctly, s/he has about $50K of earned income from salary or business, and with a $300K mortgage would have about $700K to invest.  At a conservative 4%, that should return $28K/year (on average).  A $300K mortgage at 3.5% for 30 years would be only about1350/month, or about 21% of income.

Comment: @cf2017 that is up to high riskaverse you are - if you take out a huge mortgage to buy a house and invest all your cash in other securities, then you will probably have a hard time if "shit hits the fan" - can you accept the risk of potentially losing your money (and your house if your job goes away?). If you put everything in the house, you will probably always have a place to live, and your "investment" will be somewhat safe, however it will not yield anything until you sell. On the other hand - if you are not riskaverse, you can probably get bigger returns if not investing all in the house.

Comment: @cf2017 That being said - I think you will find it hard to find someone who is willing to lend you 7x your annual income - especially if they find out that you will be using "that" money to speculate.